# Algorithm for converting fraction to binary

Tags: algorithm, binary

The way I was taught to convert a fractional decimal to binary was to continually multiply the number by 2, add the whole portion to the bit string, and multiply again by the new fraction. This seems to work in some cases, but in other cases, like 0.32, it results in an infinite loop.

```
0.32 * 2 = 0 + .64
0.64 * 2 = 1 + .28
0.28 * 2 = 0 + .56
0.56 * 2 = 1 + .12
0.12 * 2 = 0 + .24
0.24 * 2 = 0 + .48
0.48 * 2 = 0 + .96
0.96 * 2 = 1 + .92
0.92 * 2 = 1 + .84
0.84 * 2 = 1 + .68
0.68 * 2 = 1 + .36
0.36 * 2 = 0 + .72
0.72 * 2 = 1 + .44
0.44 * 2 = 0 + .88
0.88 * 2 = 1 + .76
0.76 * 2 = 1 + .52
0.52 * 2 = 1 + .04
0.04 * 2 = 0 + .08
0.08 * 2 = 0 + .16
0.16 * 2 = 0 + .32 // Loop
```

What do I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fractions except for those of kind `K/2^M` (like 0.125, 0.75 etc) cannot be represented with limited number of binary digits, so they have infinite repeating structure like 0.11011011011011... So most of fractions are not represented exactly.

The same situation is for decimal system and denominators except for `2^p*5^q` - for example, 1/3 = 0.333333333...... and so on

Comment: That makes sense. So to follow IEEE 754 standards, Should just stop after 23 iterations, as that is the limit of the mantissa for single precision floating point numbers?

Comment: Yes. Also note that IEEE float mantissa always lies in range 0.5..1 with implicit one bit, so you need to represent 0.64 with exponenta -1 (instead of 0.32 with exponenta 0)

Comment: @richbai90 To round properly, Need 1) +1 iteration (24) to find the round bit and 2) see if any remainder exist to break half-way cases.

Comment: "most of floating numbers are not represented exactly." --> All finite `double, float` are exact and they use binary encoding.  It is decimal numbers in FP-like notation (code constants) that are not exactly convertible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your algorithm, but the algorithm for teaching long division is similar to what you're proposing. Normally, we teach long division by asking how many powers of 10 of a certain number goes into another number. This gives you the decimal answer. You can do the same thing for binary by asking how many powers of 2 of a certain number go into another number. If we want to convert 0.32 to binary, we've got to ask how many of each power of 2 there is. The powers are 0, -1, -2, etc.

Algorithm:

```
1. Start with n = 0
2. How many how many times does 2^n go into the number (should be either 0 or 1 times)? Write that down.
3. If there is a remainder, decrement n (ie, n = n - 1).
4. Go to step 2 until no remainder remains or the pattern repeats.

Put a decimal after the first digit.
```